# RCP: How to sync state of MMenuItem and MToolItem

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

I have a handler which is linked to both a menu item and a toolbar icon.  If the menu item is selected, a checkmark will appear to the left of the menu item. If the toolbar button is pressed in the icon changes to a 'sunken' to look like it's pushed in.

If the menu item is checkmarked I would like to 'auto-push' the toolbar button in (without firing another toolbar button-pressed event).

If the button is pressed in I would like the menu item to 'auto-checkmark'

Is there a way to do this?  I assume it would start here..;

```
@Execute
public void execute(
    @Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL) Shell shell, 
    @Optional MToolItem toolItem, 
    @Optional MMenuItem menuItem) {

  // Menu triggered coming into this method
  if (menuItem != null ) { 
    if(menuItem.isSelected()){
    ...
    }
  }

  // Button triggered coming into this method
  if (toolItem != null ) { 
    if(toolItem.isSelected()){
    ...
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both MToolItem and MMenuItem before the first execution. You can find MToolItem via EModelService in a @PostConstruct method.

```
private MMenuItem menuItem;
private MToolItem toolItem;

@PostConstruct
protected void initControls(MApplication app) {
    setToolItem((MToolItem) modelService.find("tool.item.id", app));
}
```

As for menu item, it cannot be found in such a way via EModelService (in Eclipse 4.3 Kepler, not sure for Luna). That is how we do that in the same @PostConstruct method:

```
...
MUIElement window = modelService.find("main.window.id", app);
setMenuItem((MHandledMenuItem) findMenuElement("menu.item.id", window));
...

public static MMenuElement findMenuElement(String id, MUIElement searchRoot)
{
    if (id == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("id is null!");
    }

    if (id.length() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Empty string is not allowed in id.");
    }

    if (searchRoot instanceof MMenuElement && id.equals(searchRoot.getElementId()))
    {
        return (MMenuElement) searchRoot;
    }

    if (searchRoot instanceof MTrimmedWindow)
    {
        MMenuElement findMenu = findMenuElement(id, ((MTrimmedWindow) searchRoot).getMainMenu());
        if (findMenu != null)
        {
            return findMenu;
        }
    }
    else if (searchRoot instanceof MPart)
    {
        List<MMenu> menus = ((MPart) searchRoot).getMenus();
        for (MMenu mm : menus)
        {
            MMenuElement findMenu = findMenuElement(id, mm);
            if (findMenu != null)
            {
                return findMenu;
            }
        }
    }
    else if (searchRoot instanceof MMenu)
    {
        List<MMenuElement> children = ((MMenu) searchRoot).getChildren();
        for (MMenuElement me : children)
        {
            MMenuElement findMenu = findMenuElement(id, me);
            if (findMenu != null)
            {
                return findMenu;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Just curious, how is that different from the @Optional tag in the execute method?

Comment: If you click on the toolbar item, menuItem in the execute  method will be null. If you click on the menu item, toolItem in the execute method will be null. And you need both of them in order to call setSelected method.